# Updating information with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, updating

Please tell me what I have done wrong. I think there may be a `$_POST` error but I am new to PHP and just need a hand.

```
<?php

include("config.php");
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

$medical=$_POST['medicalin'];

    if($medical=='')
    {
        echo"<script>alert('Please enter some Medical Information, if there is none to report, simply type N/A.')</script>";
       exit();
    }

//updating
$query = "UPDATE test SET medical= '$medical' WHERE id=".$user['id'];

if(mysql_query($query)) {
    echo"<script>window.open('/success','_self')</script>"; }

else {
   echo "There was an error updating your medical information, please contact us immediately.";}

}

?>
```

Comment: where you define $user['id'] ?

Comment: why compare with `''` and not `empty()`

Comment: later up in a another file, but ive already got this: $query = " UPDATE test SET last_login = NOW() WHERE id=".$user['id'];

Comment: Dont use `mysql_*` instead use `mysqli_*` or PDO as `mysql_*` is deprecated and removed as of PHP7

Comment: ok @SuperDJ ill try that

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. You should use [mysqli](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) prepared statements with bound parameters as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: your script is open to SQL Injections. Do not post directly user input but use prepared statements instead

Comment: Please describe the problem more detailed! Do you get an error? What does this script do and what does it not?

Comment: @MaKobi I am getting the error or "There was an error updating your medical information, please contact us immediately."